# how to get attached tableview cell in swift

Tags: swift, uitableview

I am new to swift programming. I have attached an image with 3 pieces. The first piece contains mail tableviewcontroller with a cell with a disclosure indicator. the second piece is the second table view cell, which will be presented upon clicking the selected time in the first tableview.

When I select any cell in the second tableview, the text of it should be passed into first table view and both labels should be presented Selected time label and Time label text from the second table view, just like in 3rd piece in the attached image (taken from iPhone Settings -> Touch ID and passcode -> Require passcode). please help me with appropriate logic to achieve the third piece in the attached image.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea.

You can have the first **TableView** with cells with a disclosure indicator that when the user taps on them you push another ***controller*** with another **TableView** where the user is making the selection, upon selection, you dismiss the second ***controller*** and using protocol&delegation (or any other option you think appropriate) send the information to the first **TableView** and **.reloadData()**

**Good luck!**